# Does MySQL Subquery consider Limit from Parentquery?

Tags: mysql

Does MySQL Limit the inner query:

```
(SELECT followId FROM followings WHERE followerId = '$userId')
```

with the Limit from the "ParentQuery"?

```
SELECT id, fullname FROM users 
WHERE id IN 
(
 SELECT followId FROM followings 
 WHERE followerId = '$userId'
) 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 20 <--- is normally Pagination with offset and limi
```

If not, what should i do, that not all follower id's get fetched? I have the feeling that this query is really bad for performance.

Comment: Why not check it out to see what happens? Also, I hope you are not building that query by string concatenation?

Comment: How should i check if the inner query reads all the id's, or stops if the limit from the parent query is already finished?

Comment: The result would be the exact same.

Comment: The limit only applies to the outer query. The subquery runs against everything, and returns a list of all `followID` rows. The outer query then runs to do the matching for the `WHERE` clause, and then the `ORDER BY` is applied, and then after that the limit is applied. You can see this for yourself by reviewing the execution plan for the query.

Comment: Thanks that's all i wanted to know.

Comment: You can improve the query by getting rid of the subquery altogether and using an INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: Yes i know, the problem is i really don't understand how inner join works. At least not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, u.fullname
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT followId
            FROM followings
            WHERE followerId = '$userId'
            ORDER BY followId DESC
            LIMIT 0, 20
         ) AS f
    JOIN users AS u  ON f.followId = u.id
    ORDER BY u.id DESC  -- yes, repeated
    -- unnecessary here: LIMIT 0, 20
```

With

```
followers:  INDEX(followerId, followId)
```

Notice how this *starts* with `$userId`.

Comment: Thanks but i already found another solution.

Comment: @Pitchbloas - Present your solution as another Answer.  (Then "accept" the best.)